# What is the right way to define custom Platform for CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am migrating makefiles project to CMake. This project is using a proprietary compiler, linker, archiver. This compiler is nothing near gcc/clang-like, so it can not be natively "understood" by cmake.

The project is cross-compiled to embedded hardware. I found a guide for cross-compilation for CMake - https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux and the first thing they ask me to do is to define CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.

The issue is that my target platform does not exist among existing platforms https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules/Platform, so as I understand, I need to define it.
What is the right way to do this?

In the end, I want to support both linux clang x86 builds and cross-compilation build with proprietary compiler for embedded system.

Comment: Just create the files. Ex.: https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/-/tree/master/cmake/Platform . But there's no poing in creating a "custom platform" and also custom compiler detection files if you're working on just one project. Just do `set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)` and write a toolchain file that uses your compiler. It's not the "right way™", it's the working way that get's the job done in time.